# How to avoid calling FieldCollectionItemEntity::deleteRevision

Tags: migrations, entities

Sorry about the confusing name. I have the following problem. I have a migration for a content type that has a multivalue field-collection-item (~50 items there in average per content). The migration is fairly quick, 150 items/min. However the migration-update is very slow, 10 items/min. I've checked with xhprof and 95% of the time it spends inside `FieldCollectionItemEntity::deleteRevision` - basically deleting the old field collection items when re-populating the node with the new ones.

The content type has the revisions turned off, so the number of related revisions should be 1 all the time, not more. Is there any smart way to avoid this massive time that it takes?

I'm wondering if the Entity API has a queue system to save these delete operations for later. Or somehow removing revisions completely?

Thanks you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Copy and Paste your own version of the `FieldCollectionItemEntity` class file and call it like `FieldCollectionItemEntity2`. Then simply like have `FieldCollectionItemEntity::deleteRevision` return or do a NO-OP. Use the new class in your migration instead of the default one you're using now.

For when the migration completes; implement like a [PostImport()](https://drupal.org/node/1343112) function to delete all but the most recent revision.

To my knowledge there is no Queue of revision items. A node/entity Save (and revisioning) I thought is done in a sql `transaction` statement.

Comment: Hi Tenken, that is a great idea. What I'm worried about is missing deleting a cache (or other things than just deleting the revision) at the end - if it's necessary at all. I'll check if it's possible. Thank you!